# Spark cluster full of heartbeat timeouts, executors exiting on their own

Tags: apache-spark, configuration

My Apache Spark cluster is running an application that is giving me lots of executor timeouts:

```
10:23:30,761 ERROR ~ Lost executor 5 on slave2.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 177005 ms
10:23:30,806 ERROR ~ Lost executor 1 on slave4.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 176991 ms
10:23:30,812 ERROR ~ Lost executor 4 on slave6.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 176981 ms
10:23:30,816 ERROR ~ Lost executor 6 on slave3.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 176984 ms
10:23:30,820 ERROR ~ Lost executor 0 on slave5.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 177004 ms
10:23:30,835 ERROR ~ Lost executor 3 on slave7.cluster: Executor heartbeat timed out after 176982 ms
```

However, in my configuration I can confirm I successfully increased the executor heartbeat interval:
[image]

When I visit the logs of executors marked as `EXITED` (i.e.: the driver removed them when it couldn't get a heartbeat), it appears that executors killed themselves because they didn't receive any tasks from the driver:

```
16/05/16 10:11:26 ERROR TransportChannelHandler: Connection to /10.0.0.4:35328 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong.
16/05/16 10:11:26 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Cannot register with driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.0.0.4:35328
```

How can I turn off heartbeats and/or prevent the executors from timing out?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The answer was rather simple. In my `spark-defaults.conf` I set the `spark.network.timeout` to a higher value. Heartbeat interval was somewhat irrelevant to the problem (though tuning is handy).

When using `spark-submit` I was also able to set the timeout as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.network.timeout 10000000 --class myclass.neuralnet.TrainNetSpark --master spark://master.cluster:7077 --driver-memory 30G --executor-memory 14G --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 8 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000 path/to/my.jar
```

Comment: Heartbeats let the driver know that the executor is still alive and update it with metrics for in-progress tasks. spark.executor.heartbeatInterval should be significantly less than spark.network.timeout - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: this didn't work for me, I had to use 

--conf spark.network.timeout=10000000

Comment: With identical values for `spark.network.timeout` and `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval`, I received the following error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The value of spark.network.timeout=10000000s must be no less than the value of spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000s.` Increasing `spark.network.timeout` to `100000001` resolved this.  However note @evgenii's comment above referencing http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: do you know how to set it in Zeppelin?

Comment: Setting `spark.network.timeout` higher will give more time to executors to come back to driver and report its heartbeats. While `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` is the interval at executor reports its heartbeats to driver. So in case if GC is taking more time in executor then `spark.network.timeout` should help driver waiting to get response from executor before it marked it as lost and start new. Refer this - (https://github.com/rjagerman/mammoth/wiki/ExecutorLost-Failure:-Heartbeat-timeouts)

Comment: - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The value of spark.network.timeout=10000000s must be no less than the value of spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000s.

Comment: Isn't this just a band aid?

Answer (score 71):

Missing heartbeats and executors being killed by YARN is nearly always due to OOMs. You should inspect the logs on the individual executors (look for the text "running beyond physical memory"). If you have many executors and find it cumbersome to inspect all of the logs manually, I recommend monitoring your job in the Spark UI while it runs. As soon as a task fails, it will report the cause in the UI, so it's easy to see. Note that some tasks will report failure due to missing executors that have already been killed, so make sure you look at causes for each of the individual failing tasks.

Note also that most OOM problems can be solved quickly by simply repartitioning your data at appropriate places in your code (again look at the Spark UI for hints as to where there might be a need for a call to `repartition`). Otherwise, you might want to scale up your machines to accommodate the need for memory.

Comment: I had the same problem and `repartition` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Unless you're application jar is 150MB and you have 200 executors trying to dowload it from the AM.  Spark isnt smart enough to treat an _active_ jar download as a non-dead node.  And its heartbeat pings are blocked by the download.

Comment: @ScottCarey's point was really useful for deciding whether I should increase timeout or increase memory. When I have a large application to download increasing the network timeout should be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using pyspark, changing spark context's configuration will solve this problem. You can set it as following (Note all mentioned time are in ms) and heartbeatInterval (default 10000) should be lesser than the timeout (default 120000)

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("applicaiton") \
.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "200000") \ 
.set("spark.network.timeout", "300000")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Hope this solves your problem. If you face any further errors, vist the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html)