# Amazon EMR Pyspark: rdd.distinct.count() failling

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, rdd, emr, amazon-emr

I am currently working with an EMR cluster connecting to RDS to gather 2 table.

The two RDD created are quite huge but I can perform .take(x) operations other them.

I can also perform more complex operations such as:

```
info_rdd = somerdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[2])).groupByKey().map(some_lambda)
apps_rdd = apps.join(info_rdd).map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0], x[1][1][0], x[1][1][1])))
```

But doing the following operation to count the number of distinct users imported from RDS do not work:

```
unique_users = rdd.distinct.count()
```

I have tried many configuration to see if it was a memory issues before (just in case but it does not solve the problem) ...

These are the errors I am getting now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hadoop/AppEngine/src/server.py", line 56, in <module>
run_server()
File "/home/hadoop/AppEngine/src/server.py", line 53, in run_server
AppServer().run()
File "/home/hadoop/AppEngine/src/server.py", line 45, in run
api = create_app(self.context, self.apps, self.devices)
File "/home/hadoop/AppEngine/src/api.py", line 190, in create_app
engine = AppEngine(spark_context, apps, devices)
File "/home/hadoop/AppEngine/src/engine.py", line 56, in __init__
self.unique_users = self.ratings.distinct().count()
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in count
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1032, in sum
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 906, in fold
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco

File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in  stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.5 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, ip-172-31-3-140.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 13): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 13 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 164253 ms
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Comment: I'm referring to the message in exception `ExecutorLostFailure (executor 13 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 164253 ms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for the problem was the following:

I did not have enough memory to perform the task.
I changed the type of the core instance I was using in my cluster to instance with more memory available (m4.4xlarge here).

Then I had to precise parameters to force the memory allocation of my instances for the spark-sumbmit:

```
--driver-memory 2G
--executor-memory 50G
```

You can also add these parameters to avoid a long task from failling because of the heartbeat or the memory allocation:

```
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=XXX (large number such as 1024 or 4096)
--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=60s
```

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning your RDD on the key(both having the same number of partitions) prior to the join and groupBy ? If you do, please let me know about the result.

Answer (score 1):

**ExecutorLostFailure Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 164253 ms**

This error means that the executor didn't respond after 165 seconds, and was killed (under the assumption that it is dead)

If by any chance you have a task which occupy the executor for such a long time, and is need to be executed you can try the following setting in the `spark-submit` command line which will increase the heartbeat timeout to a huge amount of time as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260231/5088142

Some methods how to investigate this issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37272249/5088142

---

The below will try to clarify some issues which raised in your question.

[**Spark Actions vs Transformations**](http://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf)

Spark uses lazy computation, i.e. when you perform `transformation` it doesn't execute it. Spark execute only when you perform `action`

In the complex operations example you gave there is no action (i.e. nothing was executed/computed):

```
info_rdd = somerdd.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[2])).groupByKey().map(some_lambda)
apps_rdd = apps.join(info_rdd).map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0], x[1][1][0], x[1][1][1])))
```

Reviewing [spark doc about transformation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations)

You can see that all operation used in the example: `map`, `groupByKey` and `join` are transformation.

Hence nothing actually was done after you execute those commands.

**The difference between actions**

> The two RDD created are quite huge but I can perform .take(x)
>   operations other them.

There is a difference between `take(x)` action, and `count`

`take(x)` action ends after it returned the first x elements.

`count()` action ends only after it pass the entire RDD

The fact that you execute some transformation (as in the example) which were *seems to be running* has no meaning - as they weren't executed.

Running `take(x)` action can't give any indication as it will use only very small portion of your RDD.

**Conclusion**

It seems like the configuration of your machine doesn't support the size of the data you are using, or your code create huge tasks which cause the executors to hang for a long period of time (160 seconds).

**The first `action` which was actually executed on your RDD was the `count` `action`**